# Access 2010: ColumnHistory syntax

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I read lots of forums and blogs and I'm not able to find solutions for my problem...

I wanted to display a "ColumnHistory" in a text field using following formula in the "Control source" field

```
=ColumnHistory("Test","Comments","[ID]=" & Nz([ID],0))
```

where:

- "Test" is the table name
- "Comments" is the name of the column that is set to memo and to records historical data
- [ID] is the default/automatic ID field that came with the table

All of the above works fine, until I want to query not by the ID field, but by a different field named "TID", so if I just replace ID with TID in the formula, it returs #Error

Interesting observations:

1. As soon as remove "Primary key" from the "ID" field, the formula also returns #Error
2. If I add primary key to "TID" field and adjusting the formula it still does not work-#Error
3. Returning primary key back to the "ID" field with the original formula works just fine

Any idea how I can make this formula work without the ID field?

Comment: On a rough test, the way I got an error was by referring to a field that contained duplicates. Whether or not it was indexed seemed to be irrelevant. Check the data type and check for duplicates. A text type will need quotes.

Comment: Hello! I do not have any duplicate records as I am testing with just 2 records in the table. All I'm changing is [ID] to [TID] in the formula, where [TID] is just another text column. Also, you're right whether the record is indexed or not it doesn't matter, however it still works only with [ID] column only...Thoughts?

Comment: Is TID a text column? If so, you need quotes `ColumnHistory("Test","Comments","[ID]='" & [TID])` No matter what the column is, skip Nz.

Comment: TID is a text column. The forumula you provided returns blank value...The way I read your formula is that [ID] should equal [TID], considering its two different columns, they would never equal.

Comment: I can only help you so far, you need to work with me a little. What do you want TID to equal? You have not mentioned a field, so I provided a rough guide, though I notice it is missing a final quote: `ColumnHistory("Test","Comments","[ID]='" & [TID] & "'")`

Comment: OMG, it worked! I guess that missing quote was the key, also I changed [ID] to [TID], so complete formula end up being `code` =ColumnHistory("Test","Comments","[TID]='" & [TID] & "'") `code` Thank you for being patient and helping me out!